# Cassandra PHP extension not load by Apache

Tags: php, apache, cassandra, homebrew

I install the Cassandra PHP extension ( [both pecl and C/C++ driver](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) )

and run the following code in the terminal:

```
<?php

var_dump( extension_loaded('cassandra') );
```

the Cassandra extension is loaded:

```
❯ php index.php
bool(true)
```

but, when I run the above code with browser, I get the different result:

```
bool(false)
```

I use the Apache to be the Web Server on Mac (El Capitan) with PHP 5.6.22 (PHP is installed by Homebrew), and it seems like that Apache does not load the Cassandra extension.

I have added the extension to php.ini:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/cassandra.so"
```

but it still not work.

Comment: Did you turn it off and back on again? ... no, seriously, reboot Apache

Comment: If restarting Apache doesn't fix it, check that your Apache and CLI versions of PHP use the same php.ini.

Comment: I have restarted the Apache, but it still not work. My Apache and CLI versions of PHP use the same php.ini ( /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini )

Comment: Is there a error in phpinfo?